# Obtain all comments posted to a Facebook social comments page using FQL

Tags: facebook-fql

Is there a way to use FQL to obtain the XID of all comments posted on any page associated with a particular Facebook application ID?

The docs listed for FQL on the comments_info table at this address seem to suggest that it is possible:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comments_info/

If I attempt the following query however, it returns no results.

SELECT xid FROM comments_info WHERE app_id = {MY_APP_ID}

I want to use this to find the most popular pages without individually checking each URL to determine which one has the most posts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve all comments with FQL by application ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206372/retrieve-all-comments-with-fql-by-application-id)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get comments from the Comments plugin, try the *comment* FQL table instead. Legacy fb:comments were auto-migrated to the latest version a while ago, effectively rendering *comments_info* obsolete.

From the *comments_info* docs page:
"Note: This table contains a mapping of app_id to XIDs used by legacy fb:comments. It does not contain a map for the current comments plugin, which does not use XIDs."