# Retrieve all comments with FQL by application ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments, app-id

We use the facebook comment plugin to have comments on our site.

To moderate those, we use this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

However, we want to build our own tool to moderate those comments, and integrate it to our existing software.

I can't find a proper way of doing this. the only way I found out now after hours of research is this FQL query:

```
select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='URL_HERE')
```

That doesn't work because we have thousands of different URL's and I cant query each of them every time to see if there are any new comments.

I need a way to get all (new) comments by just enter our app_id, domain or something like that

How can I do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, after researching this issue for about a day, I found it is only possible if you have a fixed set of sub-pages you want to fetch comments from. See the answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10412716/280503

Answer (score 2):

I'm considering doing the same thing- grabbing all user posts for my application. I'm assuming it's a similar task.

For given user, I will scroll through feed and home looking for app posts. For you, you'd go:

```
`home?fields=comments`
`feed?fields=comments`
```

And check for "type" and "id" to match your application.

Comment: Anna when you field comments from an object it is just a sample of the comments and likes, not all.  you have to query the connection.

/post_id/comments

Answer (score 0):

This code queries for all comments xids used by your application:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT fromid, text, id, time, username, xid, object_id FROM comment WHERE xid IN (SELECT xid FROM comments_info WHERE app_id = {0}) ORDER BY time desc&access_token={1}&format=json
```

Comment: For new comments this not works. FB: `Note: This table contains a mapping of app_id to XIDs used by legacy fb:comments. It does not contain a map for the current comments plugin, which does not use XIDs.` [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comments_info/)