# Facebook FQL query to return all comments against an application

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve all comments with FQL by application ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206372/retrieve-all-comments-with-fql-by-application-id)

Evening,

I was wondering if anyone knows how to use FQL to return all comments associated to an Application.  The app_id.

select text from comment where ????

Based on changes by facebook, the new fb-comments don't have the XID value so this is not an option.

The only place I can see all comments is using

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?ID=

But I would like to query all of the application comments using FQL.

I can't use the URL, because it is different depending on where the comment was posted.

Any feedback would be great.

Thanks

Chris