# Retrieve all the comments posted using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a website & have placed social plugin on all of my webpages. What I want is to retrieve all the comments posted on my site on different pages via my APPID

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT xid from comments_info where app_id=myappid
```

I have tried this url with accesstoken at [Facebook developer's page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

The output I get is

```
{
     "data": [
     ]
}
```

I tried querying this up to get the latest comments posted using my appid but that doesnt work. I dont want to grab comments from one specific webpage but from all the pages of my domain where users has used social plugin attached with my appid to post a comment.

Anyone has solution to it ?

Comment: protip: add (json) responses as text rather than screenshots/images

Comment: Unfortunately, after researching this issue for about a day, I found it is only possible if you have a **fixed** set of sub-pages you want to fetch comments from. See the answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10412716/280503

Comment: I tried to mark this question as a duplicate of [this stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206372/retrieve-all-comments-with-fql-by-application-id/10413570#10413570) question, but since it is not a facebook.stackoverflow question it wouldn't let me.

Comment: Me too. Can you solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list all comments in my domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203158/how-to-list-all-comments-in-my-domain)